# How to implement conditional CSS in this situation?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, if-statement

Am using this function

http://bavotasan.com/2012/a-better-wp_link_pages-for-wordpress/

And calling it within template with this

```
<center><span class="post-pagination"><?php custom_wp_link_pages(); ?></span></center>
```

However, the CSS shows even on pages that don't contain multipaged articles.

So I guess I need something like

```
 <?php if $multipage then  <center><span class="post-pagination"><?php custom_wp_link_pages(); ?></span></center><?php endif; ?>
```

But obviously this would result in errors.

Need help with syntax for including in the template or proper way of implementing it into the function itself.

$multipage is a variable that already exists and contains the data that tells if the current page is multi or no.

Comment: In the article you provided, there is already a `$multipage` check. Why didn't you use it?

Comment: I need the proper syntax for implementing it in the template  or properly introducing it into the function so the CSS only shows when $multipage is true. I understand the logic. What I need is the proper syntax / line of code.

Comment: Where is your CSS file? It is not in your question

Comment: You can check `$multipage` global variable and print content. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$multipage` is a global variable, so you can use following;

```
<?php
if ( $multipage ) :
?>

<center><span class="post-pagination"><?php custom_wp_link_pages(); ?></span></center

<?php
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Ahh! Yes. It works. I didn't see this earlier. Was looking at above thread. Thank you man.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, first you create the template for the page in which you need pagination.

Then select that newly created template in page. That's it.